# Not able to print the desired output with these python lists

Tags: python

I want my source code output to be like this:

```
Lists: 1 3 4 2 1 2 1 3; 4 4 2 4 3 2 4 4 3 1 3    
[2, 3]

Lists : 1 1 2 3 4 5; 2 3 4 5 6    
[]

Lists : ;   
[]

Lists:
```

I want to write a function which takes two lists and  returns back all the elements that occur multiple number of times in both lists but instead I end up finding common elements in these lists. My return list should be in ascending order without duplicates.

```
def occur_multiple(a, b):
    a_set = set(a)
    b_set = set(b)
    # check length  
    if len(a_set.intersection(b_set)) > 0:
       return (a_set.intersection(b_set))
    else:
       return ("no common elements")

while True:
    original_string = input("Lists: ")
    if not original_string:
        exit()
    first_split = original_string.split(';')
    first_list, second_list = [elem.split(' ') for elem in first_split]
    first_list.sort()
    second_list.sort()
    print(occur_multiple(first_list, second_list))
```

Comment: add in question expected result. Using `set()` you remove "multiple occurrences" so you can't find them

Answer (score 0):

The count function for list might be helpful for your task. I have modified your code so that it go through the element in the intersection set and check if the count in both list is more than 1.

```
def occur_multiple(a, b):    
    a_set = set(a)    
    b_set = set(b)
    # check length
    ans_set = set()
    c = a_set.intersection(b_set)
    if len(c) > 0:
        for i in c:
            if a.count(i) > 1 and b.count(i) > 1:
                ans_set.add(i)
        return (sorted(list(ans_set)))
    else:
        return ("no common elements")
```

Also, you might like to change your list input into ints. For improvement, you might like to store the counts of each element in dictionary rather than reading the list multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Using NumPy functions `np.unique` and `np.intersect1d`:

```py
import numpy as np

def my_fun(a, b):
    val_1, count_1 = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)       # Find unique elements and 
    val_2, count_2 = np.unique(b, return_counts=True)       # number of occurrences

    val_1 = val_1[count_1 > 1]                              # Retain elements occurring
    val_2 = val_2[count_2 > 1]                              # more than once

    result = np.intersect1d(val_1, val_2)                   # Set intersection
    return list(result)                                     # Convert to list
```

```py
>>> a = [1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3]
>>> b = [4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 3]
>>> c = my_fun(a, b)
>>> print(c)
[2, 3]
```

```py
>>> a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> b = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> c = my_fun(a, b)
>>> print(c)
[]
```

```py
>>> a = [-5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 0, 1, 2, 4, 4, 2, -5]
>>> b = [1, 3, 4, 5, -5, -5, -5, 1, 4]
>>> c = my_fun(a, b)
>>> print(c)
[-5, 1, 4]
```